# When to use Action Overflow Menu vs Modal List

Tags: mobile, web-app, android, design-patterns, ios

For a mobile web app when would you use an action overflow menu as opposed to a modal window list?

**Here is an example of a modal window list used on Instagram App (android):**
[image]

**Here is an example of a action overflow menu from an app (Android):**[image]

Answer (score 2):

They both accomplish the same objective: Show options hidden under a button that collapses multiple options under it.

The benefit of adding a dark overlay is to visually allow the user to focus on the the options.

Answer (score 0):

From a UX perspective I see no difference in the two. If your OS guidelines do not prescribe what to do, I'd say it's a matter of taste in visual design.